# Confusion about the architecture of Conan

Tags: conan

I'm trying to grasp how Conan works, and learning the docs of Conan. 
 So what I got so far is that from the client side, the client writes a `conanfile.txt` file that contains a `[requirements]` section, in which all the requirements for the project is specified. 
When the client runs `conan install` - Conan reads the settings of the client from the `~/.conan/profiles/default` (or another profile can be specified through the Conan CLI also) and downloads the relevant binary package from the remote (given that it isn't present in the local cache already) corresponding to the profile (like OS, architecture, etc).

My confusion starts at the producer side. This is what I got so far: In order to create a package, you need to write a `conanfile.py` which is refered to as a *recipe*. This recipe describes the building of the binary packages.

The [docs](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/getting_started.html) say that the `conan create` is equivalent to:

```
$ conan export . demo/testing
$ conan install hello/0.1@demo/testing --build=hello
# package is created now, use test to test it
$ conan test test_package hello/0.1@demo/testing
```

Some points I don't understand:

1. Why does the client download the recipe? Isn't the recipe needed only for the package creation?
2. Why does a client's profile contain a `compiler` bit? I can understand the `os` and `arch` for example, since a X86-Windows client machine can't handle a Linux package or a ARM package, but why does a compiler is part of the configuration specified by the client?
3. The recipe contains a line `settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"` The docs say:

> The settings field defines the configuration of the different binary packages. In this example, we defined that any change to the OS, compiler, architecture or build type will generate a different binary package. Please note that Conan generates different binary packages for different introduced configuration (in this case settings) for the same recipe.

where is it speicifed exactly which configurations to build in the package creation process?

4. `conan install` is used both for package creation and both for package consuming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some answers:

> 1. Why does the client download the recipe? Isn't the recipe needed only for the package creation?

Yes, the client downloads the recipe because if a binary is not available for a required package ID, that recipe will be used to build sources. Not all configurations are available in `conan-center`.

Also, [build options](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/consumer/install.html#build-options) in `conan install` command will affect its behavior. Downloading the recipe is more convenient, than downloading only the package.

This behavior won't change, because it's part of Conan 1.0 and would break many users which consume their recipes from Conan cache.

> 2. Why does a client's profile contain a compiler bit? I can understand the os and arch for example, since a X86-Windows client machine can't handle a Linux package or a ARM package, but why does a compiler is part of the configuration specified by the client?

Different compilers provide different binaries. On Windows you can use gcc from mingw, or MSVC. On Linux you can use clang or gcc, they are compatible most of time, but generate different binaries, including optimization level. Also, there are other important flags related to each compiler, like, libcxx (libstdc++, libc++, libstdc++11), or Runtime for MSVC (MT, MD). Some compiler versions only support C++11 (GCC 4.9), so you must be sure about compiler compatibility when building a project. Basically, it affects the [ABI compatibility](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/define_abi_compatibility.html).

> where is it specified exactly which configurations to build in the package creation process?

The package generation is documented, please, read:

- [Understand Packaging](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/understand_packaging.html)
- [Development Flow](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/developing_packages/package_dev_flow.html)
- [Supporting Different Paradigms](https://blog.conan.io/2017/03/07/Supporting-Different-C-C++-Package-Paradigms-with-conan.html)

> 4. conan install is used both for package creation and both for package consuming?

If you want to develop a new simple recipe, in your machine, build it and use, so `conan create` is the way. You will use [conan create](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/creator/create.html) for 90% of cases when creating a new recipe. You can read [Development flow with Conan Create](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/developing_packages/package_dev_flow.html#conan-create) section for more information.

On the other hand, [conan install](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/consumer/install.html) is used mainly for package consuming, but it can be used for package creating too. When?

- [Development flow](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/developing_packages/package_dev_flow.html#conan-install)
- When you want to install a package, but you also want to build it from sources.

The reason behind is because `conan install` came first, it was used for both proposes, but we needed something more straightforward for package creation, so `conan create` was introduced. However, as we couldn't remove a feature, due backward compatibility rule, `conan install` still can be used as package creator.